# program to remove special characters and number from string and only print english letter

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

**this is what i tried.**
**this works properly for small string like wel$co*me 
but gives weird output for pass@word. where am i going wrong exactly?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char s[100],rs[100];
    int i,c=0;
  scanf("%s",s);
  int n = strlen(s);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(((int)s[i] >= 65 && (int)s[i] <= 90) ||((int)s[i] >=97 && (int)s[i] <= 122)  )
    {
      rs[c] = s[i];
      c++;

    }

    else
    {
      continue;

    }
  }
printf("%s",rs);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: c or c++ ? please pick one

Comment: A small string? `"wel$co*me"` is the same length as `"pass@word"`

Comment: Missing _null character_.

Comment: [Off Topic] `else { continue; }` is not needed in the for loop.  If you drop it the for loop will continue anyways.

Comment: Please note the library function `isalpha()` which is portable and more readable than hard coding what I suppose are ASCII values.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, and `isalpha()` is often called wrong with a potential signed `char` and it has locale dependences, but other than that, its great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but gives weird output for pass@word. where am i going wrong exactly?

`printf("%s",rs);` expects `rs` to be a pointer to a *string*.  Yet without a certain *null character* in the data pointed to by `rs`, the result is *undefined behavior* or in OP's case, "weird output".

A simple solution is

```
rs[c] = '\0'; // add this after the loop
printf("%s",rs);
```

---

Another important one is to avoid buffer overruns - use a width limit.

```
// scanf("%s",s);
scanf("%99s",s);
```

---

Code has other weaknesses, yet this are the key ones for now.